# print a key array when part of the string is a variable

Tags: php

I am a beginner in php, and I would like to do something very simple :
I have :

```
$names: 
0 => test0
1 => test1
2 => test2

$_POST[arraytest0] => bla0
$_POST[arraytest1] => bla1
$_POST[arraytest2] => bla2
```

and what I want to do is to print bla0, 1 and 2 using a loop, but I don't know the syntax. 
For example,

```
echo $_POST['array.$names[0]'];
```

doesn't work.
Thank you!

Comment: reconsidering this array structure would probably be a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just concatenate the string literal (that needs quotes) with the variable (that doesn't):

```
echo $_POST['array' . $names[0]];
```

In a loop that becomes:

```
foreach($names as $name) {
    echo $_POST['array' . $name];
}
```

Or with double quotes you can embed the variable in the string, which will be evaluated:

```
foreach($names as $name) {
    echo $_POST["array$name"];
}
```